# Get the corresponding row of the button clicked in an Angular Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to get the corresponding row of the button clicked in an Angular Material table?
Under row I mean an object where I can see all values of all cells of the row.

Something like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="EditButtonCol">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>EditButtonCol</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <button mat-button (click)="onEdit(CORRESPONDING-ROW)">Edit</button>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

The is a way it works:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
(mouseenter)="selection.select(row)" 
(mouseleave)="selection.deselect(row)"
[ngClass]="{ 'selected': selection.isSelected(row)}">
</tr>
```

I use **selection** property to set the row in the `<tr>` tag when I hover cursor on a row. And then by the time the edit button is clicked the **selection.selected** prop is set and I can use it from typescript

```
onEdit() {
console.log(this.selection.selected);
}
```

But I don't like this way because if a user navigates to the "edit" button with a "tab" button and hits enter - he will be getting a wrong row or an undefined because hover never happened.

Comment: Isn't `element` what you want to pass to onEdit(). If I understand the examples correctly, it is the current element being displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this based on my working setup.  I'm sure about element but row works.  I have three buttons in this column for working with member info.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries)

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="EditButtonCol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EditButtonCol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-button (click)="viewProfile(row.member_id)">View</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="deleteRecord(row.member_id)">Delete</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="editRecord(row.member_id)">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Yes you're right - it works. And I don't know ... it must be sort of black magic because I've tried it before and read in the [Angular Material API-guide](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatCellDef) that **Cell definition for the mat-table. Captures the template of a column's data row cell as well as cell-specific properties.** but it would return me an empty object ... Now it's okay and it returns me an object of the row with props for each column and its values. Btw  "let row" - I've checked and you can use any variable name instead of row - it's just a name that's up to you

Comment: Dima, I started with Mat Table as soon as it was available.  Not much documentation but I was told I had to use row.  The table worked when I did.  However, I'm seeing element used more now so I guess there has been a change.  Or maybe I had a different name for each column.  Thanks for the tip!  I've added my Stackbliz example to my answer.  I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<button mat-button (click)="onEdit(element)">Edit</button>
```